# Error when trying to extend validator in Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I have been using the following validation for my form in Laravel:

```
public function isValid($data, $rules)
    {
        $validation = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if($validation->passes()){
            return true;
        }

        $this->messages = $validation->messages();

        return false;
    }
```

The rules passed to it are simple:

```
$rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required'
        ];
```

And `$data` is the input post data. Now I need to add a custom validation extension to this, specifically to make sure that the value of input field `round2` is greater than the value of input field `round1`. Looking at the docs, I have tried the following syntax which I think should be correct, but I keep getting an error.

```
        $validation->extend('manual_capture', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
        {
            return $value > $parameters[0];
        });
```

Then I could call this with `$attribute = 'round1'`, `$value = $data['round1']` and `$parameters = [$data['round2']]`.

The error is `Method [extend] does not exist.` - I'm not sure if my understanding of this whole concept is correct, so can someone tell me how to make it work? The docs only have about 2 paragraphs about this.

Comment: Take a look at http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_addExtension

Comment: @chba This is Laravel 4.2...and also I've been through the docs, I don't see why my way shouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in your route.php

```
Validator::extend('manual_capture', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value > $parameters[0];
});
```

Additional documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Then use it like so:

```
$rules = [ 'foo' => 'manual_capture:30'];
```

Comment: I know, but how do I attach that to my `$validation` variable? That's the real issue here. When I do it that way, there is no error, but it also doesn't validate the round1/round2 relation.

Comment: You mean how to use it?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it comes down to that. I'm looking at the docs but I don't see how to add this custom rule to the existing `$validation`.

Comment: I see the edit you've made - sorry but could you clarify a bit more? How do I pass the parameters? What is '30' in your example? That line of rules should somehow have three things passed to it: the field to validate, its value and the value of the other field so we can compare them.

Comment: The field I'm trying to validate here is called `foo` and it's value is passed automatically to validation rule through `$value` as an argument. The value I'm trying to compare with `foo` is passed through parameters as an array, which in my example is `30`.